# Format a Excel Cell Range as a Table using NPOI

Tags: c#, excel, npoi

[image]

I'm using NPOI to manipulate Excel(.xlsx) file data & format. I was wondering if there is a way to format the cell range to the table.

```
// something like.
ITable table = worksheet.FormatAsTable("A1:C4");
```

Have done some research on the internet but no luck yet. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: [This link](https://thinktibits.blogspot.com/2014/09/Excel-Insert-Format-Table-Apache-POI-Example.html) can be useful: it's a sample for Java POI, but NPOI is its .NET port and has similar (if not same) API.

Comment: It works!! Thank you so so much!!

Answer (score 7):

**[2021/05/28 Update]**:
Thanks for reminding. Found that without setting ctTable's *id, name and displayName* would get this error `Removed Part: /xl/tables/table1.xml part with XML error. (Table) Load error. Line 1, column 247.` (Following sample code fixed.)

---

Based on comment and [link](https://thinktibits.blogspot.com/2014/09/Excel-Insert-Format-Table-Apache-POI-Example.html) offered by @Gian Paolo, the C# way to achieve 'format as table' with NPOI would be like this:

Install-Package NPOI -Version 2.5.3

```
// NPOI dependencies
using NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.Spreadsheet;
using NPOI.SS.UserModel;
using NPOI.SS.Util;
using NPOI.XSSF.UserModel;


IWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
XSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.CreateSheet("Grades") as XSSFSheet;

InsertTestData(worksheet);

// Format Cell Range As Table
XSSFTable xssfTable = worksheet.CreateTable();
CT_Table ctTable = xssfTable.GetCTTable();
AreaReference myDataRange = new AreaReference(new CellReference(0, 0), new CellReference(3, 2));
ctTable.@ref = myDataRange.FormatAsString();
ctTable.id = 1;
ctTable.name = "Table1";
ctTable.displayName = "Table1";
ctTable.tableStyleInfo = new CT_TableStyleInfo();
ctTable.tableStyleInfo.name = "TableStyleMedium2"; // TableStyleMedium2 is one of XSSFBuiltinTableStyle
ctTable.tableStyleInfo.showRowStripes = true;
ctTable.tableColumns = new CT_TableColumns();
ctTable.tableColumns.tableColumn = new List<CT_TableColumn>();
ctTable.tableColumns.tableColumn.Add(new CT_TableColumn() { id = 1, name = "ID" });
ctTable.tableColumns.tableColumn.Add(new CT_TableColumn() { id = 2, name = "Name" });
ctTable.tableColumns.tableColumn.Add(new CT_TableColumn() { id = 3, name = "Score" });

using (FileStream file = new FileStream(@"test.xlsx", FileMode.Create))
{
    workbook.Write(file);
}
```

```
// Function to Populate Test Data
private void InsertTestData(XSSFSheet worksheet)
{
    worksheet.CreateRow(0);
    worksheet.GetRow(0).CreateCell(0).SetCellValue("ID");
    worksheet.GetRow(0).CreateCell(1).SetCellValue("Name");
    worksheet.GetRow(0).CreateCell(2).SetCellValue("Score");
    worksheet.CreateRow(1);
    worksheet.GetRow(1).CreateCell(0).SetCellValue(1);
    worksheet.GetRow(1).CreateCell(1).SetCellValue("John");
    worksheet.GetRow(1).CreateCell(2).SetCellValue(82);
    worksheet.CreateRow(2);
    worksheet.GetRow(2).CreateCell(0).SetCellValue(2);
    worksheet.GetRow(2).CreateCell(1).SetCellValue("Sam");
    worksheet.GetRow(2).CreateCell(2).SetCellValue(90);
    worksheet.CreateRow(3);
    worksheet.GetRow(3).CreateCell(0).SetCellValue(3);
    worksheet.GetRow(3).CreateCell(1).SetCellValue("Amy");
    worksheet.GetRow(3).CreateCell(2).SetCellValue(88);
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I'm trying your method, but I get this error when I open the excel file: "Removed Part: /xl/tables/table1.xml part with XML error.  (Table) Load error. Line 1, column 247."

Comment: @RobNone Have the same issue. Did you resolved it?

Comment: @KamilSpisak answer updated, could see if it works.

Comment: @Rohim Chou Thanks a lot, it's working like a charm! Furthermore I've managed to add filtering to headers by using:

`ctTable.autoFilter = new CT_AutoFilter();
 ctTable.autoFilter.@ref = myDataRange.FormatAsString();`

Then the result looks exactly the same as in question's screenshot.

Comment: @KamilSpisak Just in case someone comes looking for filters, setting the @ref prop didn't work for me. To get filters working, I had to do the following:
`ctTableCatStat.autoFilter = new CT_AutoFilter();`
`ctTableCatStat.autoFilter.filterColumn = new List<CT_FilterColumn>();`
`ctTableCatStat.autoFilter.filterColumn.Add(new CT_FilterColumn() { colId = 1, showButton = true });` This last one just repeat for each column 
you want filtered

Comment: I had to add a row count to avoid getting this error.  CTTable.tableColumns.count = 25, in my case.

Comment: I was creating few tables in one workbook but on different sheets. For creating Id used `ctTable.id = (uint)(sheet.GetTables().Count + 1)` which was creating same Ids in workbook scope. After generating unique Id in whole workbook with this method `uint GetTableId(ISheet sheet) { IWorkbook workbook = sheet.Workbook; int tableId = 0; for (int i = 0; i < workbook.NumberOfSheets; i++) { tableId += ((XSSFSheet)workbook.GetSheetAt(i)).GetTables().Count;}  return (uint)tableId;}`
issue was resolved

Answer (score 2):

Not enough rep to add a comment - but if anyone is getting strange Excel errors when everything looks fine, I had an issue with iterating an object list into tableColumn. Building an array first fixed all my issues:

```
var headerNames = _headers.Select(x => x.Name).ToArray();
for (uint i = 0; i < headerNames.Count; i++)
{
    ctTable.tableColumns.tableColumn.Add(new CT_TableColumn() { id = i + 1, name = headerNames[i] });
}
```