# Create total row in xlsx file using NPOI

Tags: c#, .net, excel, xlsx, npoi

I'm trying to create a Table inside xlsx with a Total row. I am using this solution as an example.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65178752/format-a-excel-cell-range-as-a-table-using-npoi](https://stackoverflow.com)

The problem is that I am also trying to add a Total Row. But for some reason, the cell with the value of Total Row remains empty.

My code:

```
        XSSFTable xssfTable = sheet.CreateTable();
        CT_Table ctTable = xssfTable.GetCTTable();
        AreaReference myDataRange = new AreaReference(new CellReference(2, 1), new CellReference(totalRowNumber, 8));
        ctTable.id = 1;
        ctTable.name = "Table1";
        ctTable.displayName = "Table1";
        ctTable.tableColumns = new CT_TableColumns();
        ctTable.tableColumns.tableColumn = new List<CT_TableColumn>();
        ctTable.totalsRowShown = true;
        ctTable.totalsRowCount = 1;

        ctTable.tableColumns.tableColumn.Add(new CT_TableColumn() { id = 1, name = "Service", totalsRowLabel = "Total"});
        ctTable.tableColumns.tableColumn.Add(new CT_TableColumn() { id = 2, name = "Price" });
        ctTable.tableColumns.tableColumn.Add(new CT_TableColumn() { id = 3, name = "Times performed", totalsRowFunction = ST_TotalsRowFunction.sum});
```

I've tried calling EvaluateAllFormulaCells but it didn't work out.

The result I want to get
[image]